# How can I end this code before it is applied to the list of references?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, programming, code

I use this code to make the chapter title in a single page without the page number

```
 \assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\textls[40]}[\clearpage]
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {12pt}
    {\Large}
    [\clearpage]{}
```

But when implementation is applied to all, I am only applied to the chapters. The problem applies to references and exposes it on one page.

How can I finish the code before it applies to the references list

Fore example

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\leftmark }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\textls[40]}[\clearpage]
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {12pt}
    {\Large}
    [\clearpage]{}

\begin{document}
simple example 
\chapter{ch1}
\chapter{ch2}
% RESULTS
%\input{include/Results}

% CONCLUSION
%\input{include/Conclusion}

% REFERENCES / BIBLIOGRAPHY
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%\input{include/backmatter/References}

% APPENDICES
\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{Roman}           % Capitalized roman numbering starting from I (one)

%\input{include/backmatter/Appendix_1}


\end{document}
```

When you type the reference list, the title is on one page as in the picture[image]

The code should be applied only to the titles of the chapters

Answer (score 1):

You  also can use  the `numberless` key to have a different formatting for unnumbered chapters:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
        {\filcenter\Large\bfseries}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {}
```

Note this command can be used in the body of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I used `\begin{titlepage}` `\end{titlepage}` and succeeded

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\leftmark }
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \graphicspath{ {images/} }
        \usepackage{titlesec}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \begin{document}
        simple example 
\begin{titlepage}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\textls[40]}[\clearpage]
        \titleformat{\chapter}
            [display]
            {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
            {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
            {12pt}
            {\Large}
            [\clearpage]{}
        \chapter{ch1}
        \chapter{ch2}
\end{titlepage}
        % RESULTS
        %\input{include/Results}

        % CONCLUSION
        %\input{include/Conclusion}

        % REFERENCES / BIBLIOGRAPHY
        \cleardoublepage
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
        %\input{include/backmatter/References}

        % APPENDICES
        \cleardoublepage
        \appendix
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \pagenumbering{Roman}           % Capitalized roman numbering starting from I (one)

        %\input{include/backmatter/Appendix_1}


        \end{document}
```

Comment: In the long run, this might have negative side effects. But you can simply replace `\begin{titlepage}....\end{titlepage}` by `{...}`.

Comment: @samcarter How to Replace, Can You Write What You Mean

Comment: Instead of `\begin{titlepage}` write `{` and instead of `end{titlepage}` write `}`.